# Multiplying certain cells listed by row index in a dataframe column by a constant

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to multiply certain rows in a column that satisfy an if statement of being less than one by a constant. I have included the creation of the indices I have so far below.

```
rowIndex=df.index[df['columnName'] <= 1]
```

Comment: `df.loc[condition, column] *= constant`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `df.loc[df['columnName'] < 1, 'columnName'] *= c`.